# How to get product random collection in magento2?

Tags: magento2, product, collection, php-7

I want to get the random 10 products from whole product collection in magento2.

```
$productCollection = $this
        ->productModel
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$productCollection->getSelect()->orderRand();

$productCollection->setPagesize(10);
```

How to get the products without loading the whole product collection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
// Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $_collection
$collection = $this->_collection->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
           ->getSelect()->orderRand()->limit(10);
```